# Черный экран после установки Archlinux на VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, archlinux

В первый раз ставлю арч, решил попробовать на виртуалке. Процесс установки прошел нормально, следовал [гайдам с арчвики](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)). После ребута и окна груба : черный экран и ноль реакции.
Параметры основной ОС:

```
OS: Ubuntu 15.10 wily
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.2.0-38-generic
Uptime: 4h 48m
Packages: 2798
Shell: bash 4.3.42
Resolution: 1280x1024
DE: Unity 7.3.3
WM: Compiz
WM Theme: Cenodark-red
GTK Theme: Cenodark-red [GTK2/3]
Icon Theme: Shadow-Red-S
Font: Ubuntu 11
CPU: Pentium Dual-Core CPU E6600 @ 3.066GHz
GPU: GeForce GT 630
RAM: 1442MiB / 7983MiB
```

Настройки VM:

```
Тип ОС:Arch Linux (64-bit)
Основная память:768 МБ
Процессор(ы):1
Предел загрузки ЦПУ:100%
Порядок загрузки:Гибкий диск, Оптический диск, Жёсткий диск
VT-x/AMD-V:Включены
Nested Paging:Включено
Интерфейс паравиртуализации:По умолчанию
Видеопамять:12 МБ
3D-ускорение:Выключено
2D-ускорение видео:Выключено
Сервер удалённого дисплея:Выключен
Контроллер: IDE
Вторичный мастер IDE (Оптический привод):archlinux-2016.06.01-dual.iso (744,00 МБ)
Контроллер: SATA
SATA порт 0:arch.vdi (Обычный, 8,00 ГБ)
Аудио драйвер:PulseAudio
Контроллер:ICH AC97
Адаптер 1:Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (NAT)
COM-порты Выключены
Фильтры устройств:0 (0 активно)
Общие папки:Нет
```

Настройки grub дефолтные, сгенерированиы grub-mkconfig.
Настройки grub:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После отработки grub-а:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

fstab:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите скриншот конфигурации загрузчика grub (параметры ядра и проч.). Попробуйте вручную указать ядро/рамдиск из командной строки grub и запустить загрузку.

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поисковики её проиндексируют. приведите, пожалуйста, ссылки на установочный образ и инструкцию, которой следовали. также покажите, пожалуйста, параметры, передаваемые *grub-ом* программе *linux*. исправить вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: попробуйте загрузиться, удалив из параметров, передаваемых программе *linux*, директиву `quiet` (это в строке, начинающейся со слова `linux`).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin
Спасибо за совет , после удаления quiet ничего не изменилось. Установочный образ с оф. сайта от 2016.06.01,инструкция - с арчвики "Installation Guide".

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что после окончания работы *grub* не появляется вообще ни строчки текста?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Именно

Comment: судя по дополнительной информации, в конфигурации *grub-а* указана некорректная информация по поводу *uuid* блочного устройства. раз вы смогли загрузить какую-то систему в этой виртуальной машине, приведите, пожалуйста, вывод команды `blkid`.

Comment: скорее всего, в приведённой информации вы не обнаружите устройства, упомянутого в конфигурации grub и в выдаваемой им ошибке. т.е., вам надо повторить конфигурацию grub (согласно использованной вами инструкции), только не забудьте предварительно примонтировать все разделы, которые вы монтировали при установке (опять-таки, согласно всё той же инструкции).

Comment: Спасибо всем большое за помощь. Проблема решилась неренастройкой груба.

Answer (score 1):

судя по дополнительной информации, в конфигурации *grub-а* указана некорректная информация по поводу *uuid* блочного устройства, с которого должна производиться загрузка.

раз вы смогли загрузить какую-то систему в этой виртуальной машине, то, следуя той же инструкции, выполните переустановку/переконфигурирование загрузчика *grub*. только не забудьте предварительно примонтировать все разделы, которые вы монтировали при установке (опять-таки, согласно всё той же инструкции).