# Как переименовать основную ветку Git?

Tags: git, git-branch

У меня был проект который я никак не могу залить нормально на gitlab и вот в этот раз вроде все получилось нормально, но когда пишу в терминале

```
git branch
```

то мне показывает все доступные ветки(в моем случае она одна)

```
aleksey@aleksey:~/Downloads/NTZ/FittingRoom$ git branch
* new
```

И она у меня называется почему то `new`...

Хотя это когда на прошлом репозитории был у меня проект я там пробовал создавать ветки и была там такая `new`, но потом вроде все удалял...

В общем теперь у меня главная ветка называется `new` ...

Как это исправить?

ПРАВКА

```
aleksey@aleksey:~/Downloads/NTZ/FittingRoom$ git branch -a
* master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

переименовать локальную ветку можно той же командой `branch`:

```
$ git branch -m старое-имя новое-имя
```

Comment: Так я так понял, что команда `git branch` показывает мне все ветки и те которые на сервере тоже... Я так понял, что это не локальная ветка `new` а та которая на сервере... Или нет?

Comment: без опций/параметров команда `branch` отображает только локальные ветки. с опцией `-r` — только удалённые, с опцией `-a` — и те и другие.

Comment: А можете еще подсказать, вот я к вопросу добавил что у меня выводит команда `git branch -a` и там 3 ветки... одна локальная `master` и две остальные выходит, что удаленные... Но почему две? и как понять эту `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master`

Comment: в файле `HEAD` содержится ссылка либо на ветку (как в вашем случае), либо на commit (т.н. [detached head](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/541931/178576)). если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым.